# Function headers

Tags: c++, function

this is more of a confusing question problem where i dont really understand what the question wants me to put down as an answer.

Question:
Write function headers for the functions described below:

(i) The function check has two parameters. The first parameter should be an integer number and the second parameter a floating point number. The function returns no value.

Thats just the first one since all im really looking for is maybe an example of some kind for what i should put down as an answer. If anyone can help me out with this it would be wonderful.
Thanks!

Comment: Think *prototypes*. `void f(int, float);`

Answer (score 0):

`void check(int, float);`

(Normally I'd give the parameters names to help indicate semantics, but we aren't given enough information here.)